# Does a custom matcher or match_requests_on override playback repeats?

Tags: rspec3, vcr, webmock

I have an integration test for some code that sends SMS messages.

The test sends the initial message, say, "Hello, world", and uses VCR to validate the call to the external SMS provider was made via an HTTP API.

The test then simulates sending a reply to the SMS message via a controller.

On getting an indecipherable reply, the code is to send a message such as "Sorry. Does not compute." and then resend the "Hello, world."

The test looks for the call to send "Sorry..." and then looks for the call to resend "Hello, world."

However, it appears that the second "Hello, world" is not being re-sent by the code, yet the test thinks it is, since the second `expect a_request`does not fail.

I am using a custom `match_requests_on: [:uri, :method]` to match against `method` and `uri`. Since the first "Hello, world" and the second are essentially identical, is this rule yielding my false positive? I have repeats turned off, so I would expect two separate requests to have to be in the cassette or the test would fail.

What am I missing?

Comment: The vcr.log for the run can be found at https://gist.github.com/martinstreicher/a29530a7989b916e2cc5

Comment: I notice that my test is getting an exception from VCR when calling the controller. `An HTTP request has been made that VCR does not know how to handle:`

I wonder why the exception is being swallowed. It does not bubble out to the output of the test.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can look at.

1. I think it is a problem that the VCR exception is not being raised. Are you using any async libraries (e.g. Celluloid, ruby threads, delayed_job) for concurrency or background jobs? Something must be catching and handling the exception by printing it, which could explain why you see it, but it is not reported to rspec.
2. Your vcr.log does contain 2 interactions with twilio's Message.json, which means that with `:allow_playback_repeats => false` (the default), VCR will respond to this method/URI twice.

   ```
   [post https://SomeUUID:SomeSecretKey@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/SomeUUID/Messages.json] => [201 "{\"sid\": \"SMea17b16d31d34ce9b9ad8c6e68987b31\", \"date_created\": \"Tue, 22 Dec 2015 "], 
   [post https://SomeUUID:SomeSecretKey@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/SomeUUID/Messages.json] => [201 "{\"sid\": \"SM29ac83b5e668432e901dd75cba7bc674\", \"date_created\": \"Tue, 22 Dec 2015 "]
   ```

   Note: With `:record => :once`, VCR will record as many interactions/requests as you make, and then will freeze the cassette as read-only afterward.
3. Search your vcr.log for `[Cassette: 'cms/sms_08'] Initialized with options`. You'll notice that the cassette is being loaded twice (i.e. for two tests). Then search for `for [post https://SomeUUID:SomeSecretKey`. You'll notice that in the first, there are two Message.json requests, both of which are served successfully. In the second test, a 3rd request is made, which webmock identifies as unhandled, causing the exception you see.
4. You said you're using `expect a_request`. Are you using it with `.twice` to specify how many times? https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#setting-expectations-in-rspec-on-webmock-module